# Failed to install HipChat4 for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-installation

I have followed the installation steps [here](https://www.hipchat.com/downloads)  :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-apt-client $(lsb_release -c -s) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atlassian-hipchat4.list'
wget -O - https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hipchat4
```

But after sudo apt-get update I get :

```
....
Fetched 5,092 kB in 6s (794 kB/s)                                                                                                                                  
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-apt-client/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  

W: Failed to fetch https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-apt-client/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have already followed this exacts steps with success on a ubuntu 14.04 machine.

---

**Edit 1 -  on 64 bit, I get following error**

```
Get:2 https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com precise/main Translation-en_US [80 B]
Err https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com precise/main amd64 Packages                                                                         

Err https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com precise/main i386 Packages                                                                          

Ign https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com precise/main Translation-en_US                                                                      
Ign https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com precise/main Translation-en                                                                         
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:                                                                                  
1397BC53640DB551
W: Failed to fetch         https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-apt-client/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  

W: Failed to fetch 
https://atlassian.artifactoryonline.com/atlassian/hipchat-apt-client/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
$ sudo apt-get install hipchat4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package hipchat4
```

Comment: last comment at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/HCPUB-287 solved the issue for me